# Asignar variable php como atributo id de una etiqueta div

Tags: php, javascript, html, div

Quiero generar un `alert` al darle `click` al cada uno de los números de la tabla que se genera con el `for`. El `alert` ya funciona, pero quiero que sea el mismo número de la casilla a la que le doy click. En este caso el error es que sigue saliendo el primer valor, o sea:

```
<?php

$indice=1;
$filas = 100;

echo "<table border= 1; id='table'>";

echo "<th> Numeros </th>";

for($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div id='numero' onclick='alertNumero()'>";
    echo $indice++;
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
<script>

function alertNumero(){
    var x = document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML;
    alert(x);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que a todos los tags HTML le asignas el ID ´numero´, por lo que la función siempre toma el primero. 
Te recomiendo que asignes el $i como Indice

```
<?php    
    echo "<table border= 1; id='table'>";    
    echo "<th> Numeros </th>";    
    for($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++){    
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div id='.$i.' onclick='alertNumero('.$i.')'>";
        echo $i;
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }    
?>
<script>
    function alertNumero(e){
        alert(e);
    }
</script>

La otra opción es capturar el evento Click, y desde esa obtener el objeto que disparo el evento "alertNumero(event)", así:

<?php    
    echo "<table border= 1; id='table'>";    
    echo "<th> Numeros </th>";    
    for($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++){    
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div id='.$i.' onclick='alertNumero(event)'>";
        echo $i;
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }    
?>
<script>
    function alertNumero(event){
        alert(event.target.innerHTML());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, lo puse asì y el alert ya no funciona

Comment: Perdón, utilicé comillas simples en lugar de dobles al concatenar el índice. Ya he editado la respuesta, prueba ahora a ver que tal.

Comment: Gracias ya funciono! (soy nueva con php)

Comment: No hay de que, me alegra haber podido ayudar :)